# Getting the id of an svg element in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to save an svg element as png as instructed [here](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng). It says to use **saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("diagram"), "diagram.png");** where **"diagram"** is the id of the svg element. Now I am having trouble finding out the id.

```
                    function guid() {
                    function _p8(s) {
                        var p = (Math.random().toString(16)+"000000000").substr(2,8);
                        return s ? "-" + p.substr(0,4) + "-" + p.substr(4,4) : p ;
                    }
                    return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();
                }
                var svg = d3.select("#hiddenblock").append("svg")
                    .attr("svgid",guid())
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height+300+ margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")

                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Above I tried to give **var svg** a id name **svgid** then implemented it at the position of **diagram** but in the browser console in says **Uncaught Error: an HTMLElement or SVGElement is required; got null**. I tried to use **hiddenblock** but it didn't work.

A sample of my browser's output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2QD4.png). It seems here the  element got an id but saveSvgAsPng() function doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: It's not `svgid`, it's just `id`: `.attr("id", guid())`.

Comment: also tried with id but the result is same.and isn't it just a name?

Comment: The `saveSvgAsPng` function doesn't need the `id` of the SVG, it needs the SVG element itself...  In your case you can probably do `saveSvgAsPng(document.querySelector("#hiddenblock svg"), "diagram.png")`

Comment: Why are you assigning a GUID to your id?  You don't seem to save that value anywhere, how are you going to use it later to retrieve the svg element?  `var myGuid = guid(); ... .attr("id", myGuid) ... saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById(myGuid), "diagram.png");`

Comment: thanks very much @Mark. it worked!.but there's a slight problem.the css isn't working.instead of downloading colored image it's downloading only black.any suggestion?

Comment: @mosharaf, you need to in-line all the styles.

Comment: @Mark in (https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng) there are some **options** given but there is no instruction on how to use these.would you please tell me how should i implement these? specifically i wanted to use **modifystyle**.